# How to get the information about all groupChats in which my bot is part of. MsBot framework for Teams (nodejs)

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

When someone add my bot to their groupchat I am receiving a **ConversationUpdate** event and I am storing it for future reference. But storing all **conversationUpdate** events(which I will get when someone add my bot to their chat) of all groupChats has become a problematic. Is their any function for getting the Information about all groupChats that my bot has added to. Like we have a function for listing all **Teams** channels ex:- `TeamsInfo.getChannels(context)`

I would be thankful for any help

Comment: Well, you definitely don't need to store ALL conversationUpdate events - you only really need the first time your bot is added to a chat, to get thing like conversation id, and you only need that if your'e doing something like pro-active messaging. Perhaps that's enough already to solve your problem?

Comment: my apologies for not framing the question properly. I mean if my bot has added to 100 groupChats should I store the conversationId of all chats?. is It compulsory or Can I receive information about all groupChats ( in which my bot is part of ) by any other way without storing conversationIds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to do this - the best I could suggest is something like listing conversation members of existing chats, on the graph beta endpoint (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/conversationmember-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http). However, that would mean (a) it needs to returns bots as members of the chat, which I'm not sure it does (b) you'd need to basically query EVERY possible group chat in the organisation and (c) you'd need access rights to do that (e.g. application access). So, it certainly sounds like just storing the conversation id upfront on your own would be a better bet.

Recall that you can get the conversation id (if that's what you're looking for) from any event, not just conversationUpdate - even a regular message to your bot from a user in the chat will have the conversation id attached. Also, you've haven't stated what you  need the conversation id for. Presumably it's for pro-active messaging, but in that case remember to store the service url as well.